# Error loading SQL_VARIANT data type using Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using Python 2.7 and SQLAlchemy 0.7.8 to query a database that I did not create.

I have run into a problem querying a table that contains the `SQL_VARIANT` data type.  I get the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (Error) ('ODBC data type -150 is not
>   supported.  Cannot read column Value.', 'HY000')

I confirmed with the database creator that the "Value" column is of type `SQL_VARIANT`. Does anyone know a way to load this data type using Python? I am currently using mssql with pyodbc, the connection string is `mssql+pyodbc://user:password@IPAddress/database`.

The connection string above has allowed me to connect to and query the database for other data that doesn't use that type. According to the MSSQL page on the SQLAlchemy docs, my connection string would result in a connection of the form: `DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=IPAddress;Database=database;UID=user;PWD=password`.