# How to query a table that contains sql_variant in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, sql-variant

I am trying to query an `instance` of a `mapped class` with `sqlalchemy` that contains a column with a `sql_variant` data type. However, when executing my query, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('ODBC SQL type -150 is not yet supported.  column-index=3  type=-150', 'HY106')
```

My mapped class goes like this:

```
class ParamValue(Base):
    __table__ = Table('param', autoload=True)
```

It contains 4 columns:

```
id (PK, int, not null)
param_set_id (FK, int, not null)
param_id (FK, int, not null)
value (sql_variant, null)
```

And my query looks like this (simple query):

```
session.query(ParamValue).all()
```

Anything could help, thanks

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354042/error-loading-sql-variant-data-type-using-python

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I saw that question but it was left unanswered..! I saw that `sqlalchemy` has a `SQL_VARIANT` object, so what I will try to do is to redefine completely the columns of my `mapped class` and force the column to `SQL_VARIANT` datatype. Will post here if I find anything interesting.

Comment: One option might be to `CREATE VIEW param_view AS SELECT id, param_set_id, param_id, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, value) AS value FROM param` on the server and then use `__table__ = Table('param_view', autoload=True)`

Comment: Alright, I will look into this tomorrow. I ran some additional tests today and could not figure out so this might help. I ran into similar issues trying to use `pandas` `read_sql` method.